# PHP: Array to string? Array of Key/value pairs into simple value list?

Tags: php, arrays, string

I am sure this is something simple, but I can't find it anywhere:

How can I change an array like this:

```
{ [0]=> string(3) "674" [1]=> string(3) "675" [2]=> string(3) "676" [3]=> string(3) "677" }
```

into a simple one like this:

```
(674,675,676,677)
```

For use in another SQL (IN) query?

I have tried imploding and it fails.

```
$myarray_value = implode( ',', $myarray );
```

Comment: what language is this? add it as a tag.

Comment: you are using var_dump. can you give $array

Comment: nemo: it DOES seem to be a dupe, thanks! That solved my problem.

Comment: It should work, probably you have made any mistake or post the array that you are `var_dump`ing.

Comment: [Check this](http://codepad.org/UaIp8ioG), should work.

Comment: nemo: you should post your comment as the answer and I will accept it as correct. Thanks again for finding it.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking at is in JSON format, so just do this:

```
$string = '{ [0]=> string(3) "674" [1]=> string(3) "675" [2]=> string(3) "676" [3]=> string(3) "677" }';
$array = json_decode($string);
print_r($array);
```

Comment: The string in your answer is the result of `var_dump($array)` and not a `json` string.

Comment: [Check this](http://codepad.org/UaIp8ioG).